# what's the Largest bool malloc size? store 15 puzzle states

Tags: size, malloc

I'm using a 1D bool array to keep track of unique number,
So if the number has already exist, I mark it as 1,otherwise 0.

the largest number I need as bool index is 7004068093591806976

So When I malloc it, error happened, I wonder what's the biggest size I can malloc for a bool array?

```
bool *closelist = (bool*)malloc(7004068093591806976*sizeof(bool));
```

error message:

```
malloc: *** mmap(size=1004068093591810048) failed (error code=12)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

So I need the largest size I can have to divide this array to some subsets. Or maybe better idea?

It's to remember the 15 puzzle states to prevent duplicate states.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum amount of memory that can be allocated is system-dependent, but 7004068093591806976 bytes is 7 *exabytes* (that's 7 million terabytes). Dividing this up into multiple chunks isn't going to help. According to Wikipedia, that's about a fortieth of *all* the data storage in the world.

If you could access this storage at one byte per microsecond, it would take 222,000 years to access it all.

You'll have to find another algorithm.

Comment: the type is boolean, so I think each element would only take 1 bit instead of 1 byte?

Comment: Well every data type in C++ takes at least one byte. Even if you used a bit-vector, you're still looking at close to an exabyte. If you have that much memory, please let me know where you bought it!